# Why are the derivatives not treated the same?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

It seems to me that derivatives are treated differently in certain places, but I do not understand why.

Here is an example, if

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} (\sqrt{1 + 4x^2}) & = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1 + 4x^2}} \cdot \frac{d}{dx} (1 + 4x^2) \\
& = \frac{4 \cdot \frac{d}{dx}x^2}{2\sqrt{1 + 4x^2}} \\
& = \frac{4x}{\sqrt{1 + 4x^2}}
\end{align}

then why

$\frac{d}{dx} (1 + 4x^2) = 8x$?

Seems to me that $\frac{d}{dx} (1 + 4x^2)$ has two different answers

Comment: Notice the $2$ on the denominator $2\sqrt{1+4x^2}$disappeared

Comment: Why do you believe it has two different answers? Where does that belief come from? We can't tell you where you're erring if you don't tell us why you think what you think.

Comment: What I don't get is why $\frac{d}{dx} (1 + 4x^2)$ in the first example is $4x$ but equates to $8x$ in the seconds exmaple

Comment: Because of chain rule. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#First_proof

Comment: I get it... took me a long time to see it, thanks Tianyu

Comment: It is also 8x in the first example. However due to the 2 in the denominator, 8x/2 reduces to 4x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 
$$\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{1+4x^2}}\cdot \dfrac{d}{dx}(1+4x^2)$$

you take the derivative in the numerator to get

$$\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{1+4x^2}}\cdot \dfrac{d}{dx}(1+4x^2) = \dfrac{8x}{2\sqrt{1+4x^2}} = \dfrac{4x}{\sqrt{1+4x^2}}. $$

The $8x$ becomes $4x$ because of the cancellation by $2$ in the denominator.

A property of the derivative is $(f(x)+g(x))' = f(x)'+g(x)'$. So for your example
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}(1+4x^2) = \dfrac{d}{dx}(1)+\dfrac{d}{dx}(4x^2) = 0+ \dfrac{d}{dx}4x^2 = 4\dfrac{d}{dx}x^2 = 8x$$

So they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

They *are* the same. Note that in the first derivative, it turned out to be:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{1+4x^2}\right)=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(4x^2)}{2\sqrt{1+4x^2}}$$
$$=\frac{4\cdot \frac{d}{dx}x^2}{2\sqrt{1+4x^2}}$$
$$=\frac{8x}{2\sqrt{1+4x^2}}$$
See how the numerator does turn out to be $8x$, which is what we wanted. But the $8$ turns into $4$ because of the $2$ in the denominator